# What represent this form item object and how can I discover its content using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, xhtml

I am pretty new in JavaScript development and I have the following situation. Into a JSP page I have the following JavaScript:

```
function chiamaservizio() {
        alert("INTO chiamaservizio()")


    <%if(l.size() == 1) {

    %>
        alert("l.size == 1");
        if (form1.item.checked == true) {
            alert("form1.item.checked == true");
            var pagina = "href=edi.do?serv=3.7";
            form1.action = pagina;
            document.form1.submit();
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("<fmt:message key="nessun_doc_sel" />");
            return;
        }

    <% } else { %>
        alert("l.size != 1")
        if (GetCkValue(form1.item) == "") {
            alert("<fmt:message key="nessun_doc_sel" />");
            return;
        } else {
            alert("INTO l.size != 1 && GetCkValue(form1.item) != stringa vuota");
            alert(form1.item);
            var pagina = "edi.do?serv=3.7";
            form1.action = pagina;
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    <%}  %>
    }
```

I state that I don't know why it is mixes JSP code and JavaScript code, this is  very old web application and contains some orrible stuff...

Ok, my problem is that, as you can see in the previous code, whe I try to perform

```
alert(form1.item);
```

where **form1** is the name of a form into my JSP page:

```
<form name="form1" action="edi.do?serv=3.4" method=post onsubmit="javascript:return controllack()">
```

this alert show the following message:

```
[object HTML Collection]
```

So I think that it is something like an array but I am absolutly not sure of it.

So I want to know what it contains. What contains the **form1.item**? Is a specific content? How can I discover it? Can I convert it in a string or something like it?

Tnx

Comment: Use `console.log(form1.item)` to check object contents conveniently.

Comment: @dfsq what is this? a JavaScript instruction? Have I to put it into my JavaScript function code? Where I will obtain the output?

Comment: This is part of [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools). Just use it instead of `alert`, much more powerful. Open dev tools (F12) and check console tab.

Comment: You also might want to take a look at the action assighnment in the first branch. This results in `action="href=edi.do?serv=3.7"` which is not right!